# If given vectors in notation such as $u=i-j$, then do $i,j$ most likely refer to unit vectors?

Tags: vectors

If given vectors in notation such as $u=i-j$, then do $i,j$ most likely refer to unit vectors? So then $u=(1,0,0)-(0,1,0)=(1,-1,0)$.

As given here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector#Cartesian_coordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 common unit vectors:

$ \hat{i}  =  \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        0\\
        0\\
        \end{bmatrix} , \hat{j}  =  \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        1\\
        0\\
        \end{bmatrix} , \hat{k}  =  \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        0\\
        1\\
        \end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is common notation to use i, j and k to represent vectors, and they are unit vectors as you state.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Another commonly used notation is $e_i,e_j,e_k$, perhaps decorated with accents such as $\widehat{e}_i$ or $\vec e_i$ or in bold-face such as $\mathbf{e}_i$.